# How to tell if Siri is active during app use

Tags: ios, objective-c, siri

I have an audio app, and when `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` comes on, the app configures AV and tests for headphone use and such.

However, Siri activates the `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`, but because of the AV configuration, Siri isn't able to be used by the user (the microphone doesn't work for her, it seems.)

Is there a way to find out if Siri is the thing causing the `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`, so that I don't call the method to configure AV if it's Siri and thus let the user use Siri?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, both headphone plugging in/out and Siri activating will trigger `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`, however, notice the `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey` associated with the notification

When headphone is plugged in, the reason is `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable`

When headphone is plugged out, the reason is `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable`

When Siri is activated, the reason is `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange`

Answer (score 0):

And use below code in AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification event if you want to check Siri start or finish:

```
AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason routeChangeReason = [note.userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] integerValue];
AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* description = note.userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey];

BOOL isSiriStart = (routeChangeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange && description.inputs == nil);
BOOL isSiriFinish = (routeChangeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange && description.inputs != nil);
```