# Make iOS app detect if user is trying to call for Siri - swift

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I am wondering if you can listen to user call to Siri ? Every time Siri is opening (resulting to a "Hey Siri"), I want my app to register it. The goal would be, for example, to count the number of calls, or to do something in parallel inside my app every time Siri is called.
I know that Siri's API is quite hermetic ... is it possible ?

Comment: No. This would be a privacy violation, don't you think?

Comment: I don't want to register what the user says to Siri, just to know if Siri is called or not . I don't think that it is such a privacy violation . Anyway, here is a way to do what I wanted to achieve; even if it's not perfect , it should be enough : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933944/how-to-tell-if-siri-is-active-during-app-use .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, no, but I'll tell you another reason why.

> To avoid running the main processor all day just to listen for the
>   trigger phrase, the iPhone’s Always On Processor (AOP) (a small,
>   low-power auxiliary processor, that is, the embedded Motion
>   Coprocessor) has access to the microphone signal (on 6S and later). We
>   use a small proportion of the AOP’s limited processing power to run a
>   detector with a small version of the acoustic model (DNN).

https://machinelearning.apple.com/2017/10/01/hey-siri.html

tl;dr

You don't have permission to access what the AOP is doing, so you will **never know** when it is called.

Comment: thank you :) I've found this, this could be an interesting alternative ? (but quite incomplete) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933944/how-to-tell-if-siri-is-active-during-app-use

Comment: @BénédicteLagouge No problem. That link does look a bit interesting, but my concern would be you may build app logic around a side effect that Apple can break at any point.